# tk not installed properly in python3.6 cx_freeze compiling error on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit, cx-freeze

Background: I have never received this error as I have been working on this Python desktop program for over six months now with no compilation problems.

I wrote a new updated beta version of my python application and I went to compile the code using cx_freeze. I used the command `python3 setup.py bdist_mac`. However, I received this error when I open my build:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "TachySloth.py", line 977, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2017, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /Users/julianrachman/Documents/code/suprbotcho/versions/beta/build/TachySloth-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/tk /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Users/julianrachman/Documents/code/suprbotcho/versions/beta/build/TachySloth-beta.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5 /Users/julianrachman/Documents/code/suprbotcho/versions/beta/build/TachySloth-beta.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/tcl/lib/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/tcl/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Users/julianrachman/Documents/code/suprbotcho/versions/beta/build/TachySloth-beta.app/lib/tk8.5 /Users/julianrachman/Documents/code/suprbotcho/versions/beta/build/TachySloth-beta.app/Contents/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.

logout

[Process completed]
```

I do not know how to fix this as I have tried multiple times to install the tk requirements.

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

user_txt_path = []

if sys.platform=='win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"
    user_txt_path.append('chromedriver.exe')
    import os.path
    PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
else:
    base = None
    user_txt_path.append('chromedriver')

buildOptions = {"include_files": [user_txt_path[0], 'u.pkl', 'tcl86t.dll', 'tk86t.dll'], "packages": ['encodings', "os"], "includes": ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format'], "excludes": []}

executables = [
    Executable('TachySloth.py', base=base, icon='sloth.ico')#base)
]

'''
home_path = str(Path.home())
pathname = str(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

#for initialization
f = open(home_path + user_txt_path[0], "w+")
for i in range(12):
     f.write("---\n")
'''

setup(name='TachySloth',
      version = 'beta',
      #description = 'test',
      #shortcutName="TachySloth",
      #shortcutDir="DesktopFolder",
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables
      )
```